# SQL COUNT function for results "greater than or equal to"

Tags: sql, count

I currently have a query where it returns the total number of accounts each customer holds, but how do I make it so that it returns only customers who  has more than 1 account?

```
SELECT C.customerID, COUNT(O.accNumber) AS "total"
FROM Customer C, Owns O
WHERE C.customerID = O.customerID
GROUP BY C.customerID
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your question is `HAVING`.  However, you need to learn to use proper`JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use a comma in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT C.customerID, COUNT(O.accNumber) AS total
FROM Customer C JOIN
     Owns O
     ON C.customerID = O.customerID
GROUP BY C.customerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Actually, you don't even need the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT o.customerID, COUNT(o.accNumber) AS total
FROM Owns o
GROUP BY o.customerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

That's much simpler.

Comment: The second joinless version is only correct if we assume that all "Owns" records have a parent record in "Customer".  That seems intuitive, but might not be true.

Comment: @JosephStyons . . . They are both being joined on `CustomerId`, so it would seem that the relationship is pretty sound.

Comment: The "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" statement looks at rows where there are integers greater than 1 if I guess right here?

Comment: `COUNT(*) > 1` means that each group has more than one row. Because of the `*` it's not looking at any specific column.

Answer (score 4):

Add a HAVING clause

```
SELECT C.customerID, COUNT(O.accNumber) AS "total"
FROM Customer C, Owns O
WHERE C.customerID = O.customerID
GROUP BY C.customerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
WHERE C.customerID = O.customerID AND count(O.accNumber) > 1
```